# command to list all files on my hard drive and sub-directories to a file named files.txt

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

Windoes 8 won't allow me to list of all files on my hard drive and sub-directories using Command Prompt command to a file named `files.txt`

I used the following command `from c:\   as dir *.* /s /o > files.txt` but it gives me "Access Denied" output.

How would I write a command to list every file on my hard drive to a files.TXT file?
I know it could be a large file but I need to know every file name and directory name please.

Comment: You write "Windows 8 won't allow me to list of all files on my hard drive and sub-directories using DOS command"  <-- No. It is still Windows 8 you are using.  A cmd prompt within Windows 8 is a cmd prompt within Windows 8, it's not DOS.

Comment: A TINY bit of troubleshooting would've led you to realise that the dir /s /o worked but the creation of the file didn't, so the root of your problem was nothing to do with the DIR command.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and 8 both started restricting what could be done in the command prompt. Navigate to the Command Prompt shortcut, then right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: You write "My default Win7 installation wouldn't even recognise the IPCONFIG command!" <-- nonsense, win7 recognizes ipconfig. it's in `c:\windows\system32` that is in the path by default.

Comment: @barlop You know, you're right. I later determined that that computer had its path mangled. When I fixed it, it didn't occur to me that ipconfig would start working. When I started the command prompt as admin, though, ipconfig worked even before fixing the path... Weird. Anyway, thanks, I removed that from my answer.

Comment: ipconfig worked(despite a mangled path), when you launched cmd with administrative privileges, because the administrative cmd prompt defaults to c:\windows\system32 which is where ipconfig.exe is. The regular cmd goes to %USERPROFILE%

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a file to `C:\` unless cmd is administrative. You can load it as administrative, or you could just write a file to a directory you make, instead of to `C:\`.

So you can do this without loading cmd as administrative.

try

```
C:\>md blah
C:\blah>dir c:\ /s /o >files.txt
```